# Displaying an image from a url in JADE

Tags: image, mongodb, url, express, pug

first question here. New web development student. Thank you for your patience.

I have an application working and displaying the contents of a mongoDB in a jade layout. Inside of spans. Such as this.

```
        // USER INFO
    #userInfo
        h2 User Info
        p
            strong Name:
            |  <span id='userInfoName'></span>
            br
            strong Age:
            |  <span id='userInfoAge'></span>
            br
            strong Gender:
            |  <span id='userInfoGender'></span>
            br
            strong Location:
            |  <span id='userInfoLocation'></span>
```

My question is this. What I want to see appear inside the span is the actual image. I have the url to the image. Its on my server. The url is coming from the mongo database. I realize that storing the text url to an image in a database and then pulling that info from the database and using it to display an image may not be the ideal way to do something. I am working on a project for an assignment and wanted to try something simple. I figured pulling the url from the database and displaying it in the span would be fine. all I would need to do is wrap it in an image tag. Like this

```
<img src="http://www.whateverdomain.com/images/bobphoto.jpg">
```

It doesnt work though. I just get the url. (see attached pic)

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the contents of the spans?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using something like:

```
document.getElementById('userPhoto').textContent = (
  '<img src="http://www.whateverdomain.com/images/bobphoto.jpg">'
);
```

to set the actual image url here.  You haven't shown in your question how you set any of the other user info.  Assuming this is what you're doing, you would want to do something like:

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.whateverdomain.com/images/bobphoto.jpg');
document.getElementById('userPhoto').appendChild(img);
```

Alternatively, if you are passing the information as data into your pug template you could do something like:

```
strong Location:
img(src=userInfo.imageSource)
```